# Program for determining if aspirin is significantly better than placebo

Tags: sas

I have been tasked with the following problem:

Out of a total 1,000 subjects on aspirin, 80 had heart attacks and 65 had strokes. Out of a total 2,000 subjects on placebo, 240 had heart attacks and 165 had strokes.

I am asked if there is a significant benefit for aspirin therapy for heart attacks and strokes. What is the RR for aspirin use for each of the two outcomes?

My main issue has been setting up the data lines. Here is what I have so far, but my output window doesn't look right.

Another issue is figuring out how to account for the varying sample sizes and the fact that someone might have had a heart attack AND a stroke.

```
DATA ODDS;
   INPUT OUTCOME $ EXPOSURE $ COUNT;
DATALINES;
HeartAttack 1-Yes 80
HeartAttack 2-No 240
Stroke 1-Yes 65
Stroke 2-No 165
;
PROC FREQ DATA=ODDS;
   TITLE "Odds Ratio Aspirin";
   TABLES EXPOSURE*OUTCOME / CHISQ CMH;
   WEIGHT COUNT;
RUN;
```

Edit 1:

```
DATA ODDS;
   INPUT OUTCOME $ EXPOSURE $ COUNT;
DATALINES;
HeartAttack 1-Yes 80
HeartAttack 2-No 240
NoHeartAttack 1-Yes 920
NoHeartAttack 2-No 1760
Stroke 1-Yes 65
Stroke 2-No 165
NoStroke 1-Yes 935
NoStroke 2-No 1835
;
PROC FREQ DATA=ODDS;
   TITLE "Odds Ratio Aspirin";
   TABLES EXPOSURE*OUTCOME / CHISQ CMH;
   WEIGHT COUNT;
RUN;
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, what is it you expect your output to look like? As far as I can tell, the `datalines` statement looks fine. My only question is would you not want additional lines like `NoOutcome 1-Yes 855`?

Comment: But since they don't tell us whether or not someone could have got a heart attack and a stroke, wouldn't we not know that 855 got neither?

Comment: Oh but we do know that 855 on aspirin didn't get a heart attack.

Comment: If you look at each group independently you know that in the group with aspirin 920 didn't have a heart attack and that 935 didn't have a stroke.

Comment: I made a change to the code but now I am not getting any confidence intervals in the output. I will post the edited program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your data and code should look like. You may need to flip the order in the TABLES statement so that the Relative Risk is calculated appropriately for your situation. I didn't bother checking that this was the case, as you can easily change if required.

```
DATA HeartAttack;
   INPUT OUTCOME $ EXPOSURE $ COUNT;
DATALINES;
HeartAttack 1-Yes 80
HeartAttack 2-No 240
NoHeartAttack 1-Yes 920
NoHeartAttack 2-No 1760
;
PROC FREQ DATA=HeartAttack;
   TITLE "Heart Attack Odds Ratio Aspirin";
   TABLES EXPOSURE*OUTCOME / CHISQ CMH Relrisk;
   WEIGHT COUNT;
RUN;

DATA Stroke;
   INPUT OUTCOME $ EXPOSURE $ COUNT;
DATALINES;
Stroke 1-Yes 65
Stroke 2-No 165
NoStroke 1-Yes 935
NoStroke 2-No 1835
;
PROC FREQ DATA=Stroke;
   TITLE "Stroke Odds Ratio Aspirin";
   TABLES EXPOSURE*OUTCOME / CHISQ CMH Relrisk;
   WEIGHT COUNT;
RUN;
```

If you have the raw data I would recommend working with that instead of creating datalines in the first place. It leaves room for errors and then you could also deal with the interaction.

Comment: I didn't know I could have two separate data lines. (I'm new to SAS). I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: Datalines create datasets. It's not a particularly good way though. Usually you would read the data from a file, but I'm guessing this is a homework question.

Comment: I got odds ratio 95% confidence intervals for heart attacks and strokes of .4891,.8314 and .9605,1.7418, respectively. How would I interpret this in terms of if aspirin is beneficial or not?

Comment: I suggest reading the docs on PROC FREQ on how to interpret the results. It's very similar to your question, except its Diet and Heart Diseases vs Aspirin and Heart Disease. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_examples05.htm

Comment: That makes sense. Except for heart attacks, I got an odds ratio of about .6 which would indicate he's at a higher risk when taking aspirin

Comment: The odds ratio is 0.6. Try again.

Comment: Am I supposed to be reading the RR for column 2 so 1.0455 higher risk on placebo?

Comment: Relative Risk is different than Odds Ratio, which one are you looking for? The Odds ratio is 0.6, this means that people who take aspirin are 0.6 times less likely to have a heart attack. You should always look at the observed values, in this case, 8% of people who took aspirin compared to 12% of people who didn't had heart attacks.

Comment: Oh ok I thought odds ratio meant .6 times more likely to get a heart attack. I am asked to find RR.

Comment: That is correct, but since 0.6 times more likely is less than 1, it means it's less likely. If the ratio is more than 1 it's more likely. I suggest reviewing the basics of odds ratios and relative risk. SO isn't a forum for statistical understanding. Stats.stackexchange.com may help but this could easily be answered using wikipedia and their article on odds ratio and relative risk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk

Comment: The stroke table has an odds ratio of above 1 so that confused me. I think that is because the stroke table has the columns mixed up, with NoStroke on the left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136398/discussion-between-reeza-and-john-h).

Answer (score 1):

Placebo gives you your expected distribution. We have to handle strokes and heart attacks separately because there is no data for interaction. (If there is no interaction we'd expect a small number of patients with both, but there could be a negative or masking interaction, e.g. if the heart attacks are fatal, or there could be a cumulative interaction  heart attacks often preceded by strokes or vice versa). We can't answer any of those questions.

Once you've got you expected, it's simply two chi-squared tests with two bins each. Not one chi-squared test with 4 bins.

(I'll put in a plug for my book Basic Algorithms if you want to code the chi-squared significance test from the ground up, without using any loook-up tables).

Comment: Ok so have one variable for heart attacks and one for strokes? What do you mean by two bins each? I am new to SAS and the terminology.

Comment: We have two bins, heart attack and non-heart attack. We've got an expected number, given by the placebo, for each bin. So it's a calssic chi-squared. We then repeat for strokes. It's a different test, because we've no heart attack/stroke interaction data. (Doubtless that will come in lesson 2).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I will try to change the program accordingly.

Comment: So I added two tables (one for exposure * heartattack and one for exposure * stroke) but I am still having difficulties with the data lines.

Comment: Do you need to use datalines in the first place? Do you not have access to the raw data?

Comment: I don't have access to the raw data. Just the counts on how many got heart attacks and strokes in each of the two exposure categories.